# Error trying to get Naive Bayes classifier to run alternate training data set (Python)

Tags: python, twitter, indexing, classification

I am trying to get a Naive Bayes classifier to work on a training set of tweets for sentiment analysis. The code works perfectly on the sample.csv file I practiced. However when I try it on my training data csv file (which is formatted in exactly the same way, just bigger by about 7000 tweets) I get an index error.

Here is the particular chunk of code:

```
import csv
import nltk

#Read the tweets one by one and process it
inpTweets = csv.reader(open('SampleTweets.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
tweets = []
for row in inpTweets:
    sentiment = row[0]
    tweet = row[1]
    processedTweet = processTweet(tweet)
    featureVector = getFeatureVector(processedTweet)
    tweets.append((featureVector, sentiment));
```

The error returned is for the line

tweet = row[1]

and states 'link index out of range'.

It worked perfectly before and as a new programmer I'm really stuck.

Thanks!

Comment: the problem probably IS the data, if all you changed is the input file. Add some debug statements to your loop. For example, print out the line in the file when it fails - there are probably some special characters, or different formatting, or something of that sort.

Comment: might be additional spaces at the end of the file may get added. check it once with the input file.